# How to clear terminal in c++ and write to specific location in terminal

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I currently have no base code, and please don't recommend the ncurses library.
Here is what I want to do: I want to be able to clear the terminal window like the `clear` command but then I want to be able to write to any part of the terminal window, like how text editors work.

I know that nobody has asked this question so dont close it

Comment: FYI -- What you ask for is not possible in standard C++.  That's why libraries like ncurses exist.  As to text editors, they are way more sophisticated than what you believe they are.

Comment: please don't tell us what to do. what is wrong with ncurses?

Comment: The alternative to ncurses is painstakingly emitting terminal control codes by hand. I am still going to recommend ncurses (or a more modern TUI library like Tickit) as the least painful way forward.

Comment: *I know that nobody has asked this question so dont close it* -- This has been asked many times, here and in other places.  The answers given just aren't acceptable to you, for whatever reason.

Comment: There you go. Marked as duplicate of a question that doesn't use ncurses. Now please still go use ncurses.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I really just want to be able to do something with only the std lib.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I want to be able to write to any location in the terminal without reprinting the whole thing. like re writing the above lines.

Comment: @PranshuTheGamer -- There are no standard C++ functions that control access to the terminal in the way you are mentioning.  There is no mention of "terminal" in the C++ language.  This must all be done by something outside standard C++, and the duplicate link shows this.

Comment: "The terminal" is a separate program that is interpreting the output of your program. C++ *doesn't* define functions for interacting with your specific terminal program